# org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for:com.package, at table: user, for columns:

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, security

First let me start by saying I'm new to this site so if I've formatted this stuff wrong please point it out.

Anyway I'm trying to create a login registration application using springboot, spring security and hibernate. How ever I keep running into the above error when running. I'll be posting some code below:

My Student class:

```
@Entity
public class Student implements UserDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long studentId;
    @OneToOne(targetEntity = Role.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
    private Role role;

    private String fullName;
    private Age age;
    private String gender;
    private String email;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String college;
    private String field;
    private String major;
    private String prevExperience;
    private String educationLevel;
    private String currentlyPursuing;
    private String currentCountry;
    private String currentCity;
    private String profileTheme;
    private String careerSpecialty;
    @Lob
    private byte[] bytes;

    private int credits = 0;
    private String bio;
    private boolean enabled;
    
    public Role getRole() {
        return role;
    }
    
    public void setRole(Role role) {
        this.role = role;
    }
    
    public Long getStudentId() {
        return studentId;
    }

    public void setStudentId(Long studentId) {
        this.studentId = studentId;
    }

    public int getCredits() {
        return credits;
    }

    public void setCredits(int credits) {
        this.credits = credits;
    }

    public String getMajor() {
        return major;
    }

    public void setMajor(String major) {
        this.major = major;
    }

    public byte[] getBytes() {
        return bytes;
    }

    public void setBytes(byte[] bytes) {
        this.bytes = bytes;
    }

    public String getBio() {
        return bio;
    }

    public void setBio(String bio) {
        this.bio = bio;
    }




    public String getCareerSpecialty() {
        return careerSpecialty;
    }

    public void setCareerSpecialty(String careerSpecialty) {
        this.careerSpecialty = careerSpecialty;
    }



    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    public Age getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Age age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }
    
    
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }


    
    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()));
        return authorities;
    }
    
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getCollege() {
        return college;
    }

    public void setCollege(String college) {
        this.college = college;
    }

    public String getField() {
        return field;
    }

    public void setField(String field) {
        this.field = field;
    }

    public String getPrevExperience() {
        return prevExperience;
    }

    public void setPrevExperience(String prevExperience) {
        this.prevExperience = prevExperience;
    }

    public String getEducationLevel() {
        return educationLevel;
    }

    public void setEducationLevel(String educationLevel) {
        this.educationLevel = educationLevel;
    }

    public String getCurrentlyPursuing() {
        return currentlyPursuing;
    }

    public void setCurrentlyPursuing(String currentlyPursuing) {
        this.currentlyPursuing = currentlyPursuing;
    }


    public String getCurrentCountry() {
        return currentCountry;
    }

    public void setCurrentCountry(String currentCountry) {
        this.currentCountry = currentCountry;
    }

    public String getCurrentCity() {
        return currentCity;
    }

    public void setCurrentCity(String currentCity) {
        this.currentCity = currentCity;
    }

    public String getProfileTheme() {
        return profileTheme;
    }

    public void setProfileTheme(String profileTheme) {
        this.profileTheme = profileTheme;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student{" +
                "studentId=" + studentId +
                ", fullName='" + fullName + '\'' +
                ", age=" + age +
                ", gender='" + gender + '\'' +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", username='" + username + '\'' +
                ", password='" + password + '\'' +
                ", college='" + college + '\'' +
                ", field='" + field + '\'' +
                ", prevExperience='" + prevExperience + '\'' +
                ", educationLevel='" + educationLevel + '\'' +
                ", currentlyPursuing='" + currentlyPursuing + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Here's my Role Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long role_id;
    private String name;

    public Long getId() {
        return role_id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.role_id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Here is my user dao and the implementation:

User Dao:

```
public interface UserDao {
  Student findByUsername(String username);
}
```

User Dao implementation:

```
@Repository
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {
    @Override
    public Student findByUsername(String username) {
        Session session = SessionFactoryCreator.createSessionFactory().openSession();
        Query query = session.createQuery("from User where username = :username ");
        query.setParameter("username", username);
        Student Student = (Student) query.getSingleResult();
        session.close();
        return Student;
    }
}
```

Here is my security config file:

Security Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userService);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/assets/**");
        
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
               .anyRequest().hasRole("USER")
               .and()
            .formLogin()
               .loginPage("/sign-up")
               .permitAll()
               .successHandler(loginSuccessHandler())
               .failureHandler(loginFailureHandler())
               .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("users/details-page");
    }
    
    public AuthenticationSuccessHandler loginSuccessHandler() {
        
        
        return (req, res, authentication) -> res.sendRedirect("/");
    }
    
    public AuthenticationFailureHandler loginFailureHandler() {
        return (req, res, exception) -> {
            req.getSession().setAttribute("flash", new FlashMessage("Incorrect username and/or password. Please try again", FlashMessage.Status.FAILURE));
            res.sendRedirect("/sign-up");
        };
    }
}
```

And last but not least, the error log:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.arkan.nextstep.web.Role, at table: user, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(role)]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at com.arkan.nextstep.Main.main(Main.java:11) [main/:na]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.arkan.nextstep.web.Role, at table: user, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(role)]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.arkan.nextstep.web.Role, at table: user, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(role)]

    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:403) ~[spring-orm-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378) ~[spring-orm-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.arkan.nextstep.web.Role, at table: user, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(role)]
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.arkan.nextstep.web.Role, at table: user, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(role)]

    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:488) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:455) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:227) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:624) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:267) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:343) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:461) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1237) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391) ~[spring-orm-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please show `Role` entity

Comment: I've updated it.

Comment: Are you sure that you use `@javax.persistence.Entity` for the `Role` entity?

Comment: Yes I am. I have that imported.

Comment: `com.arkan.nextstep.web.Role, at table: user, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(role)]` - Please show your mapping for `user` table.

Comment: You have to provide User table or the pojo  of User, because the error says that he cant find column role in table user, I think you are using spring security which uses user table which have manytomany or onetomany relationship to Role table. So i recommend fixing that, then make Student class extends that User Class

Comment: Do you mean the class that is creating the table? The class that is creating the table is the student one. There is no table called user which is why the error is confusing me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of time wasting it seems like the root of the problem was that I accidently created a User class. That class was also linked to the Role table so it was throwing an
error.